# How to check if three values are all 0 or all 1

Tags: c++

There are 3 integer variables which can have values 0 or 1. If all are 0 or all are 1, print a particular statement. For all other combination of values print another statement.

I tried the following that works. Is there a better way to write the if statement?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;

    if(!(a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0) && !(a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0))
    {
        cout << "a, b or c have mixed values of 1 and 0" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "All of a, b and c are either 1 or 0" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry to have caused some confusion. Actually there is no check on the values of a,b & c imposed in the above code, since I gave it as a simple example. The if statement is not to check whether a, b & c are all equal or not. It is to check if all of them are 0 or 1 integer values (not boolean).

Comment: `cin.get()` will take the carriage return at the end of the input line where the values were captured. You'd need another one to capture a second CR. Just run it from a command window/terminal instead.

Comment: Your questions says about your integer variables that _all can have values 0 or 1_. Does this mean, they can _only_ be either 0 or 1? If yes, why do you initialise them with 10 in your code?

Comment: If I understand your latest edit, they can actually have values other than 0 or 1, correct?

Comment: @jogojapan The code could take any values of a,b & c, since there is no validation. I skipped it for simplicity. Let's assume that user will input only 1 or 0.

Comment: If that is the assumption, "checking if they are all 0 or all 1" is the same as "checking if they are all equal".

Comment: Concur with @jogojapan. If they are all strictly within [0,1], then a simple equality check is completely adequate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if( ((a & b & c) ==1) || ((a | b | c) == 0))
```

Comment: This is not correct as & is bitwise and the variables are not boolean.

Comment: Actually, it is correct since the OP said a,b and c can only have 0 or 1.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg It would work so long as all values are either 0 or 1

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - bitwise operators also work on integer types. Are you confusing it with a different programming language.

Comment: @Matthew yes, I see the restriction that is not enforced in code.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - His original code prints  "All of a, b and c are either 1 or 0" in case you pass non 0-1 values. So the assumption here is that a, b & c can contain only 0 or 1.

Comment: @user93353 His original question says that.  His code says nothing of the sort.

Comment: Assuming the domain of a, b, and c is exclusively [0,1], this code is correct.  Stated in the opening sentence of the question: "There are 3 integer variables which can have values 0 or 1."  If the domain were not set so, and the input values could be arbitrary (which the OP's code allows, but that code doesn't follow his/her own question) then this would be wrong. Honestly I'm not sure the OP understands how relevant their question formation was, as it was likely asked incorrectly, but as currently written, this code answers correctly. (+1)

Comment: @WhozCraig The OP has clarified again in the comments - the domain is exclusively [0,1]. He has omitted validations for clarity.

Comment: @user93353 I thought I pointed that out in the quote =P. Oh you mean down at the bottom. Yah. I see now.

Comment: This statement will return true when every value has first bit set to `1` and one of the values is `0x00000001`. For example: `0x00000001 & 0x11111111 & 0x00000001 == 0x00000001`.

Comment: @Broxzier - sure. But the op says his variables can have only one of two values - 0 or 1.

Answer (score 8):

In your code there is no restriction on the values that the user inputs.

If you just want to see if all values are equal to each other you can do:

```
if (a == b && b == c)
{
    cout << "A, B, and C are all equal" << endl;
}
else 
{
    cout << "A, B, and C contain different values" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a = 10, b = 10, c = 10;
cin >> a >> b >> c;

if((a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0)||(a==1&&b==1&&c==1))
{
      cout << "All of a, b and c are either 1 or 0" << endl;

}
else
{
cout << "a, b or c have mixed values of 1 and 0" << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more generic solution for C++17 users. This will allow you to compare any number of values of any type.

```
template<typename... T>
constexpr bool equal(T... args) {
    return ([&] (T arg) {
        return ((arg == args) && ...);
    }(args) && ...);
}

equal(4,4,4); // evaluates to true
equal('c','c','c','c'); // evaluates to true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( (b!=c) || (a ^ b)) 
{   
  std::cout << "a, b or c have mixed values of 1 and 0" << std::endl;
}   
else
{   
  std::cout << "All of a, b and c are either 1 or 0" << std::endl;
}
```

Another way less efficient way:

```
if( (a!=0) + (b!=0) - 2 * (c!=0) == 0 )
{
    cout << "All of a, b and c are either 1 or 0" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "a, b or c have mixed values of 1 and 0" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution: `~(~(a ^ b) ^ c)`. Based on the idea that `a XNOR b` makes sure that the two are both zero or one.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you're using C++11, you could achieve what you're looking for with variadic templates, for example:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
bool allequal(const T &t, const U &u) {
    return t == u;
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
bool allequal(const T &t, const U &u, Args const &... args) {
    return (t == u) && allequal(u, args...);
}
```

And you can call it like this in your code:

```
if (allequal(a,b,c,0) || allequal(a,b,c,1))
{
  cout << "All of a, b and c are either 1 or 0" << endl;
}
```